# Why ParameterizableWebPart get returned as an ErrorWebPart?

Tags: wss-3.0, performancepoint

I'm using WSS3.0 API to get all the webparts in an ASPX page.
The following is my code:

```
                SPFile page = web.GetFile(pageGuid);

                SPLimitedWebPartManager wpm = page.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);
                WebPartFactory factory = new WebPartFactory();
                foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart webpart in wpm.WebParts)
                {
                    //Some other logic
                }
```

This code works fine for most of the web part. But for ParameterizableWebPart, it always returns an ErrorWebPart.

The page is correctly configured, because I can view all the reports in explorer.

Have you ever encounter this problem? Or there is something wrong with my code?

Any comments are appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

PerformancePoint web parts are different animals than regular web parts.  There's [a great post on technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ppsmonitoringandanalytics/thread/3957df11-3596-45ad-89f6-f3e1e8976b0e) talking about this, with links to more information.  They were built from the ground-up chock full of AJAXy goodness.  This might be why you're getting an error when you hit that web part.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://www.get-sp.com/2010/03/errorwebpart-instead-of.html) states, that the `SPLimitedWebPartManager` will return ErrorWebParts instead of some WebParts, when not called from a web request. Maybe this is the problem in your case?